# THREE JS Mouse input Lag

Tags: javascript, three.js, mouseevent

I am creating a game where mouse input delay should be minimal. However I have noticed when you alt tab to a different window (Notepad for example) and come back there seems to be a large delay of the mouse position. When I refresh the page it will work fine again. This may be an issue exclusive to THREEJS, however I don't know for sure. Sometimes is will lag even after I refresh, but ALT + TAB seems to trigger the problem all the time for me.

Here is the code that makes the object follow the mouse to illustrate the problem:

```
function onMouseMove(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouse.x, mouse.y, 0.5);
    vector.unproject( camera );
    var dir = vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize();
    var distance = - camera.position.z / dir.z;
    var pos = camera.position.clone().add( dir.multiplyScalar( distance ) );
    mouseMesh.position.copy(pos);
    mouseMesh.position.set(event.clientX, event.clientY, 0);
};
```

Here is a fiddle that shows the problem I am having: https://jsfiddle.net/atwfxdpd/10/

To replicate the issue, simply run the fiddle. Hit Alt+Tab to change to any other window on your computer. Click on said window. Then come back.

Now when you move the mouse, the object lags behind it. Sometimes it also does it when you first run it.

My version of chrome is: Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit) (Latest)
I am on a 4K Screen. So that may have something to do with it.

EDIT: Resizing also seems to cause the issue

Comment: Tested. No lagging

Comment: Same version of Chrome? Also make sure you alt tab out and click on the window you tab out to.

Comment: Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m. No lagging.